# Android native code from web browser using javascript

Tags: android, browser, native-code

Is it possible to access android native code using javascript in the default android browser?

Regards,
Dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry.

You can create your own Android app that exposes Java objects to WebKit through the `WebView` widget. Also, you can link to Android apps from your Web content displayed "in the default Android browser" (whatever that might be for the user). And, you can arrange to have an app that you write respond to URLs that otherwise might go to a browser. But that's about it.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare! The following post would suggest this feature may be possible:  http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/android-froyo-html5-accelerometer-flash-player

(see navigator.isApplicationInstalled(app_name, callback) )
Although it is undocumented so I guess not supported.